# Do all classes need a toString method?

Tags: java

For exmaple, if I have an abstract animal class that has a toString that returns the animals name, and its child classes do NOT implement it differently, do I still need to override the toString?

Comment: No.............

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: The toString method is implemented by default in the class Object (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). This method is not abstract so you don't have to override it. You can if you want to change the string representation of you object.

Comment: The point in having a `toString` method in your abstract `Animal` class was probably exactly this: then you don’t need to declare one in the child classes (or at least in *some*  of your child classes you don’t need).

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you want the child classes to provide a more detailed description. It sounds like you're quite new to Java, so you might not understand how inheritance works (or if you do, then this question is opinion based).

The default `Object.toString()` returns very undescriptive information about an object, and plenty of classes override that. But there are classes like `AbstractList` that override it so the different `List` implementations don't have to override it themselves. The situation is pretty identical to what you described. Override `toString()` once in `AbstractList` and let `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` etc. just use that.

Answer (score 1):

toString() is a method in the Object class and in java all your class inherit the Object class so this class have toString() method

```
public class Test {
}

Test t = new Test();
t.toString(); // it's ok because it inherit the Object class
```

> toString is used to reprsent the record values to human in a readable
>   format. `System.out.println(t)`  its the same
>   `System.out.println(t.toString())` toString is for other people to see
>   what you class have so they can have an idea about you class.

sorry about my english ^^.